# Нужна исправить код, чтобы работал корректно

Tags: javascript

Задание: Дано натуральное k. Напечатать k-ю цифру последовательности 12345678910111213...,
в которой выписаны подряд все натуральные числа

Мой код:

```
<script>
    while(true) {
        var k = prompt("Введите 'k': "); //5
        var i = 1; 

        while(k > length(i)) {
            k -= length(i++);
        }
        
        while (length(i) > k) {
            i /= 10;
        }
        alert("Результат: " + i % 10);

        function length(n) {
            var result = 0;
            while (n > 0) {
                result++;
                n /= 10;
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Должен выводить натуральное число, но не выводит.
Если, например, ввести число 10, должно выводится число "1", а выводит "1e-314".
Помогите исправить проблему, пожалуйста.

Comment: вообще, странно, что это хоть как-то работает. `n /= 10;` в данном случае происходит не целочисленное деление, соответственно таким образом ты не можешь подсчитать количество цифр в десятичной записи числа. После деления нужно отбрасывать дробную часть, например с помощью [`Math.trunc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/trunc)

Comment: код сделал под синтаксис java, поэтому и проблема. Спасибо за помощь, помогло.

Comment: java и javascript - это разные языки :-)

Comment: я в курсе про языки. я пишу на java, поэтому и на js пишу как на java и думаю что будет работать, причем, осознавая, что не будет работать :)